# Vue3 Nested RouterLink is not active on load

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, routerlink

I have the main `<RouterView/>` which is responsible for the main navigation of the site. Now, one of the routes has its children as well. So in this component I've created another `<RouterView name="helper"/>` - a named one. Inside the router it looks like this:

```
{
  path: '/foo/:bar',
  name: 'foo',
  meta: { requiresAuth: true, title: 'Foo' },
  component: FooView,
  children: [{
    path: '1',
    name: 'foo-first',
    components: {
      'helper': FooFirst,
    },
  }, {
    path: '2',
    name: 'foo-second',
    components: {
      'helper': FooSecond,
    },
  }],
  props: true,
}
```

Now, the problem is with the `RouterLink`s inside the component - they are not getting the `active class` on load, only if I click on them - after this they start behave properly. The code is the following

```
...
<nav>
<RouterLink
            :to="{ name: 'foo-first', params: { bar: data.bar } }"
            class="px-1 py-4 text-base sm:text-sm"
            active-class="!text-red-600 !border-red-500"
          >
            Foo First
          </RouterLink>
          <RouterLink
            :to="{ name: 'foo-second', params: { bar: data.bar } }"
            class="px-1 py-4 text-base sm:text-sm"
            active-class="!text-red-600 !border-red-500"
          >
            Foo Second
          </RouterLink>
</nav>
...
```

What I'm trying to do - make the links become active on load as well, for instance, if I go to `some.site/foo/bar/1`, I want the first `RouterLink` to become active on load.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that inside the `RouterLink` `to` attribute you don't need to pass any `params` as they are already in the parent route. Once I got rid of them, it started working properly.